# Maximality on non-nearly normal subgroups and derived subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have troubles understanding this lemma I found in a paper on maximality of non nearly normal subgroups. 
Statement: Let $G$ be a group satisfying $Max-nn^{-}$. Then the commutator subgroup $G'$ of $G$ satisfies the maximal condition on subgroups.

Proof: If each finitely generated subgroup of $G$ is nearly normal then $G$ is an FC-group (why?) and $G'$ is finite. Therefore we may assume that the set $L$ of of the subgroups of $G$ which are finitely generated is not empty. Let $M$ be a maximal element of L. Since $M^{G}$ satisfies the maximal condition of subgroups, it follows that each finitely generated subgroup of $G/M^{G}$ is nearly normal (why?). Then $G'M^{G}/M^{G}$ is finite (why?) and $G'$ satisfies the maximal condition.

Comment: For your first question, if the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$ is infinite, then $\langle g \rangle$ cannot be nearly normal in $G$.

Comment: Ok, and it is sufficient to prove this just for 1-generated groups because of induction?